# Convert geotiff to wgs84?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff

I would like to understand how to use QGIS to convert a geotiff that I have to a projection that will work with my vector files and maybe web mapping application.  I believe I want it in WGS84 since that is what I am most comfortable with.

How would I either use QGIS or use the gdal command line tools to convert this file to WGS 84? The following is the result of running gdalinfo on it.

```
gdalinfo 1590_2602.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: 1590_2602.tif
Size is 6000, 6000
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["NAD_1983_StatePlane_Alaska_4_FIPS_5004_Feet",
    GEOGCS["NAD83",
        DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",
            SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.2572221010002,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",54],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-150],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9999],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",1640416.666666667],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["US survey foot",0.3048006096012192,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9003"]]]
Origin = (1590000.000000000000000,2605000.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.500000000000000,-0.500000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_IMAGEDESCRIPTION=OrthoVista
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=1 (unitless)
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=Trimble Germany GmbH
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=1
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=1
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( 1590000.000, 2605000.000) (150d17' 6.73"W, 61d 7'47.61"N)
Lower Left  ( 1590000.000, 2602000.000) (150d17' 6.47"W, 61d 7'18.07"N)
Upper Right ( 1593000.000, 2605000.000) (150d16' 5.64"W, 61d 7'47.74"N)
Lower Right ( 1593000.000, 2602000.000) (150d16' 5.39"W, 61d 7'18.19"N)
Center      ( 1591500.000, 2603500.000) (150d16'36.06"W, 61d 7'32.91"N)
Band 1 Block=6000x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=6000x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=6000x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

Answer (score 2):

With Qgis: 
One way is to Save As. 
Open your layer and use "Save As" option and there you have the choice to project your dataset under a new projection.

Directly with gdal :

```
gdalwarp -overwrite in.tif out.tif -s_srs EPSG:102634-t_srs EPSG:4326
```

Comment: When I switch the file name from in.tif I get the following error code ```ERROR 6: EPSG PCS/GCS code 9003 not found in EPSG support files.  Is this a valid
EPSG coordinate system?
ERROR 1: Translating source or target SRS failed:
EPSG:9003
```   That's with a .tfw in the same directory for the file, although I don't know what that does.

Comment: EPSG:9003 is not a code of coordinate system in that place but is is the code of unit. US survey foot in your case. You can have a try without -s_srs and hope that QGIS interprets CRS right automatically.

Comment: sorry, I didn"t look corectly to your gdalinfo extract. @user30184 is right. your EPSG should be "102634" if we refer to spatial reference website : http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/102634/html/